# Setup exe for Unit Test Project

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-2017

I have a Unit test project in Visual Studio C# and I am trying to make it a standalone exe. I have used Visual Studio Installer for it. On installing exe, i get the error that dlls cannot work.
1-Is it ok to make exe for Unit Test Project?
2- How do I package the dlls in setup exe or setup msi?

Comment: Not sure what you trying to achieve by making an installer for a unit test project - I'm guessing by your tags that you want to distribute this to testers? The answer may be to have an exe file which runs the tests. What test runner are you using? MSTest or something else?

Comment: But this also begs the question - if you run an unit test project as an exe - outside Visual Studio - how are you going to present the results of the tests?

Comment: I am using NUnit.. it is meant to be a quick run of the whole application showing tests being executed. results can be seen on the application itself. Yes this is for testers only.

Comment: But how are you going to present the results? You say _results can be seen on the application itself._ but I don't understand how that's going to work?

Comment: Through selenium tests in exe, some transactions will be created on the application to be tested, we will check those transactions with another test we have